# Create Array Object using for loop inside javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having below data

```
 var counts = ["2017-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-05-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-06-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-07-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-08-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-09-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-10-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-04-01T00:00:00Z", 18, "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z", 482, "2018-06-01T00:00:00Z", 272];
```

I am trying below code to get my expected result but unfortunately not getting result.

```
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    console.log(counts[i]);
    resultObj = {"date":counts[i],"post":counts[i+1]};
    result.push(resultObj);
}
```

Expected result

```
var finalResults = [{"date":"2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-09-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-10-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-11-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2017-12-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2018-02-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2018-03-01T00:00:00Z",post:0},{"date":"2018-04-01T00:00:00Z",post:18},{"date":"2018-05-01T00:00:00Z",post:482},{"date":"2018-06-01T00:00:00Z",post:272}]
```

```js
var counts = ["2017-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-05-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-06-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-07-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-08-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-09-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-10-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-04-01T00:00:00Z", 18, "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z", 482, "2018-06-01T00:00:00Z", 272];

var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
  console.log(counts[i]);
  resultObj = {
    "date": counts[i],
    "post": counts[i + 1]
  };
  result.push(resultObj);
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Instead of `i++` do `i += 2`…

Comment: Slap whoever provides you data in this format.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

```js
var counts = ["2017-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-05-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-06-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-07-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-08-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-09-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-10-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-04-01T00:00:00Z", 18, "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z", 482, "2018-06-01T00:00:00Z", 272];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < counts.length; i+= 2){
  var obj = {};
  obj.date = counts[i];
  obj.post = counts[i+1];
  result.push(obj);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Already in the comment 7 minutes ago. Is this really worth answering?

Comment: @mplungjan i was making snippet at that time. so was not able to see that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
 var counts = ["2017-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-05-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-06-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-07-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-08-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-09-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-10-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-02-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-03-01T00:00:00Z", 0, "2018-04-01T00:00:00Z", 18, "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z", 482, "2018-06-01T00:00:00Z", 272]
 
 var array = [];
 for(var i=0;i<counts.length/2;i++){
  var obj = {date:counts[i*2],id:counts[i*2+1]};
  console.log(obj);
  array.push(obj);
 }
 console.log(array);
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. It's all about the choice of algorithm solving pattern.

Comment: This is far easier to read and maintain `for(var i=0, n=counts.length; i<n; i+=2) {
  result.push({"date":counts[i], "post":counts[i+1]});
}`